# Remove duplicate key in object inside an array and aggregate count totals for each state Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have this array of objects, I want to add the count in NY but only print one time the state of NY, How can I remove duplicated keys and not hardcore 'NY' in the if statement?

> Input

```
const cityPopulation = [
{ state: 'NJ', city: 'Jersey', count: 100 },
{ state: 'NY', city: 'NYC', count: 100 },
{ state: 'CA', city: 'SFO', count: 100 },
{ state: 'NY', city: 'Albany', count: 100 },]
```

> Output

Count for state: NJ: 100
Count for state: NY: 200
Count for state: CA: 100

My approach:

```
    cityPopulation.forEach(state => {

    if (state.state === 'NY') {
        state.count += state.count
    }

    console.log(`Count for state: ${state.state}: ${state.count}`)

    }
)
```

Comment: try using array `reduce` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Super simple you can do it with a few lines of code:

```
const cityPopulation = [
    { state: 'NJ', city: 'Jersey', count: 100 },
    { state: 'NY', city: 'NYC', count: 100 },
    { state: 'CA', city: 'SFO', count: 100 },
    { state: 'NY', city: 'Albany', count: 100 },]

let results = [];

cityPopulation.map(obj => {
    if (!results[obj.state]) {
        return results[obj.state] = obj.count;
    }
    results[obj.state] += obj.count * 1
})

for(const state in results) {
        console.log(`Count for state: ${state}: ${results[state]}`);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const cityPopulation = [ { state: 'NJ', city: 'Jersey', count: 100 }, { state: 'NY', city: 'NYC', count: 100 }, { state: 'CA', city: 'SFO', count: 100 }, { state: 'NY', city: 'Albany', count: 100 },];


let res = Object.values(cityPopulation.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (acc[item.state]) {
    acc[item.state].count = acc[item.state].count + item.count
  } else {
    acc[item.state] = item
  }
  return acc;
}, {}))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this object destructuring.

```js
const cityPopulation = [
  { state: 'NJ', city: 'Jersey', count: 100 },
  { state: 'NY', city: 'NYC', count: 100 },
  { state: 'CA', city: 'SFO', count: 100 },
  { state: 'NY', city: 'Albany', count: 100 },];

let result = {};
for (const key of cityPopulation) {
  result = {
    ...result,
    [key.state]: result[key.state] ? +result[key.state] + +[key.count] : key.count,
  };
}

for(const state in result) {
  console.log(`Count for state: ${state}: ${result[state]}`);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use lodash library as:

```js
const cityPopulation = [
{ state: 'NJ', city: 'Jersey', count: 100 },
{ state: 'NY', city: 'NYC', count: 100 },
{ state: 'CA', city: 'SFO', count: 100 },
{ state: 'NY', city: 'Albany', count: 100 }];

let groupByState = _.groupBy(cityPopulation, item=>item.state);

_.forEach(groupByState, (item, key) => console.log(key, _.sumBy(item, 'count')));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```